# Code passed to exec() or eval() does not consider the classname of the invoking class to be the current class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking at this article: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Please can someone give an example that will help me to understand the below quote:

> Notice that code passed to exec() or eval() does not consider the
>   classname of the invoking class to be the current class; this is
>   similar to the effect of the global statement, the effect of which is
>   likewise restricted to code that is byte-compiled together. The same
>   restriction applies to getattr(), setattr() and delattr(), as well as
>   when referencing **dict** directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's basically telling you that the "magic" of double-underscores will not work with `exec` or `eval`, so consider the following example:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__bar = 42
...     def method0(self):
...         return self.__bar * 2
...     def method1(self):
...         return eval('self.__bar * 2')
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.method0()
84
>>> f.method1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in method1
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute '__bar'
```

Similarly, for `getattr` etc:

```
>>> getattr(f, '__bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute '__bar'
```